# Why ActivatedRoute params are null inside http interceptor?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to send a route parameter in the header of my request to the api with and interceptor. for that i injected the activatedRoute service into a custom interceptor, not sure why the params are null?

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(this.activeRoute.snapshot.params.itemGuid); //Undefined
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('sessionToken');
    let newHeaders = req.headers;
    if (token) {
      newHeaders = newHeaders.append('sessionToken', token);
    }

    const authReq = req.clone({ headers: newHeaders });

    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

AppModule.ts

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
```

[image: Null activatedRoute parameters]

If I try this, it works

[image]

Any idea why is this happening and I can get the params directly?

I am using angular 8

Comment: Do you get snapshot.params null in the intercept also?

Comment: Yes, I got the param null in the interceptor class.

Comment: Sorry seems like I asked a confusing question. Are you getting null in the intercept method in that Interceptor class? In the example, you have logged value in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, in the constructor I am getting the null values, even in the intercept method. Both

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the place where you inject the `ActivatedRoute` service.

> ActivatedRoute is a a service that is provided to each route component that contains route specific information such as route parameters, static data, resolve data, global query params, and the global fragment

We can get the queryParams or fragment but `ActivatedRoute` provides path param info only to the corresponding route component.